# How to sort by abbreviation when both abbreviation and full name is being used in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a sort function where a user will click on different states on the USA map and when they click that state a list of cities that
belong to that state is shown.

So for example I have an all button that displays all the cities in the USA, but if they click on a different state then the cities needs to filter down to
those states.

The problem I'm having is that some cities have either the full name of the state or the abbreviation.

What I would like is for my filter to be able to sort by both full name and abbreviation.

So if I click on Alabama state on the map the cities that have either 'AL' or 'Alabama' will be shown.

Here is my code

```html
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body" id="sow-index">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="btn-group btn-maps" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" v-on:click="selectedState = 'All'">All</button>
                    <button v-for="state in states" type="button" class="btn" v-on:click="selectedState = state">
                    <img :src="stateImage(state)">
                    <span>{{state}}</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="search">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="city in displayCities">
                    <td>{{city.name}}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedState: 'All',
      meta: {},
      states: ['AL', 'CA', 'KS', 'OH'],
      search: '',
      state: 'All',
      cities: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    stateCities() {
      return ('All' === this.selectedState) ? this.cities.filter(city => {
        city.state === this.selectedState
      });
    },
    filteredCities() {
      return ('' === this.search) 
        ? this.stateCities 
        : this.stateCities.filter(city => this.getSearchString(city).indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getSearchString(city) {
      let string = city.name;
      return string.replace('null', '').trim().toLowerCase();
    },
    stateImage(state) {
      return "/states/image_" + state + ".jpg";
    },
    allCities() {
      axios.get('/api/state/cities').then((response) => {
        this.cities = response.data.cities;
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.allCities();
  }
}
```

For now I've only added 4 states in my code.

Here is an example of the output of cities

```
    cities: array(50)
        0: 
            name: Athens
            state: Alabama
        1: 
            name: Greenville
            state: AL
```

Comment: Also, `mounted` should not be in your `methods` object

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to make your `states` values contain both abbreviation and full name.

For example

```js
data: () => ({
  selectedState: null,
  states: [{
    name: "Alabama",
    abbr: "AL"
  }, {
    name: "California",
    abbr: "CA"
  }, {
    name: "Kansas",
    abbr: "KS"
  }, {
    name: "Ohio",
    abbr: "OH"
  }],
  search: '',
  cities: [],
})
```

In your template, bind these object values to `selectedState`

```html
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn"
  @click="selectedState = null"
>All</button>
<button 
  v-for="state in states"
  :key="state.abbr"
  type="button"
  class="btn"
  @click="selectedState = state"
>
  <img :src="`/states/image_${state.abbr}.jpg`"> <!--  don't use methods for rendering -->
  <span>{{state.abbr}}</span>
</button>
```

Then in your computed method, use both properties for matching

```js
stateCities: ({ selectedState, cities }) => {
  if (selectedState) {
    return cities.filter(({ state }) =>
      selectedState.abbr === state || selectedState.name === state)
  }
  return cities
}
```